# Maatwebsite 3.1: Set the cell value

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

In our project, we used the latest version of maatwebsite which is 3.1

We want to set the first value for example in E1.

In lower version, they have the setcellValue.

Question: Does 3.1 have the equivalent setCellValue?

Note: I tried the startCell but that is not what I want, it moves all the columns

Answer (score 0):

[maatwebsite](https://laravel-excel.com/) uses [phpspreadsheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Having maatwebsite object, you can get phpspreadsheet underlying object with [macro](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/extending.html#macroable), and after that, you can manipulate sheet with phpspreadsheet methods, for example [setCellValue](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/accessing-cells/).

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about exporting, this may be the answer [WithCustomStartCell](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/collection.html#custom-start-cell). Yet it only available for ToCollection method.

```
namespace App\Exports;

use App\Invoice;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithCustomStartCell;

class InvoicesExport implements FromCollection, WithCustomStartCell
{
    public function collection()
    {
        return Invoice::all();
    }

    public function startCell(): string
    {
        return 'B2';
    }
}
```